# Looping/Map/Iterating over object results in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error, but data is present

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that gets data from an API end point. For the purposes of debugging when I call the API I log the result of the API call to the console and it looks like this:

[image]

The problem I have is that when I try to render the BreadCrumbLinks Property in my component I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
> at BreadCrumbHeader

I am getting an "Undefined" error, but I know that the data is present because I can read and render all of the other fields (for example `BreadCrumbBgImage`).

Also, if I comment out the map/loop the rest of the data is displayed correctly when the page loads. Then if I uncomment it out and save the file the data for the map/loop now shows correctly.

I can only assume that the code is trying to render the contents of the loop before it has been loaded.

This is what the code for the component looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import API from "../../API";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BreadCrumbTitleSection, SubtitleSection, Subtitle } from './breadCrumbHeaderStyle';
import { Breadcrumb } from 'react-bootstrap';

function BreadCrumbHeader() {
    const location = useLocation();

    const [breadCrumbData, setBreadCrumbData] = useState([]);

    const getBreadCrumbData = async () => {
        const breadCrumbHeaderResponse = await API.fetchBreadCrumbHeader(location.pathname);
        setBreadCrumbData(breadCrumbHeaderResponse);

        console.log("OUT-PUT-OF-API-CALL");
        console.log(breadCrumbHeaderResponse);
        console.log("END-OF-OUT");

    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getBreadCrumbData();
    }, [location.pathname]);

    return (
        <div>

            <BreadCrumbTitleSection backgroundUrl={breadCrumbData.BreadCrumbBgImage}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row no-gutters">
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-xl-prefix-1 col-xl-11">
                            <h1 className="h3 text-white">{breadCrumbData.BreadCrumbTitle}</h1>
                            <Breadcrumb>
                                {breadCrumbData.BreadCrumbLinks.map(breadCrumbLink => (
                                    <Breadcrumb.Item href={breadCrumbLink.LinkUrl} key={breadCrumbLink.Id} active={breadCrumbLink.IsActive}>
                                        {breadCrumbLink.LinkText}
                                        </Breadcrumb.Item>
                                ))}
                            </Breadcrumb>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </BreadCrumbTitleSection>
            <SubtitleSection>
                <Subtitle> {breadCrumbData.SubTitle}</Subtitle>
            </SubtitleSection>
     </div>
    );
}
export default BreadCrumbHeader;
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can solve i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to map data before its fetched, so its an empty array (initial value of breadCrumbData state). You should use optional chaining:

```
 {breadCrumbData?.BreadCrumbLinks?.map(breadCrumbLink =>
```

Comment: That worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You are tryng to map your array before the state change, the useEffect is called on first render, your array don't have the state in the first render, you can use something like a loading hook, like this

```
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() =>{
        setLoading(true)
        fetchData()
    },[])
    const fetchData = () =>{
        //my api call
        setLoading(false)
    }
    return (
        {loading ? (
            // my loading message or function
        ): (
            // my show component 
        )}
    )
```

this is a just an litle example how you can do